# How knowing number of images in flow_from_directory

Tags: python, keras, data-generation

We can generate image dataset using ImageDataGenerator with flow_from_directory method.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255, #scale images from integers 0-255 to floats 0-1.
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2, # zoom in or out in images
    horizontal_flip=True) #horizontal flip of images
train_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(..)
```

and that displays:

```
Found 200 images belonging to 2 classes
```

I would like to write a loop for to count the number of images on train_set

```
For image in train_set:
    count = count+1
print(count)
```

but this does'nt display anything!!

Answer (score 24):

To get the no. of images, try with the below code.

```
train_set.samples
```

Comment: This is the answer!

Comment: Finally found the answer!

Comment: Is there a way to get the number of samples for each class?

Comment: If case someone need need to know number of labels:  len(train_generator.class_indices)

Comment: train_set.n would do too.

Comment: 3 years later, this is still VERY relevant, thank you

Answer (score 4):

To access the number of samples of your dataset you first must know which type it is:

If you are using the ImageDataGenerator then:

```py
type(train_ds)
```

will return
tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator.
In this case you can access the number of samples with:

```py
train_ds.samples
```

However, if you are creating your creating your dataset using:

```py
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory( rescale = 1/255. , etc...)
```

then

```py
type(train_ds)
```

will return tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset
which means that you can access the number of samples indirectly with

```py
len(train_ds.file_paths)
```

Answer (score 0):

**__iter__** will be your solution.

first you try to predict type of **train_set** .if you do not know.

```
print(type(train_set))
#then you find **keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator**
```

Now you want to apply some function or modification on this type data follow this link[here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/DirectoryIterator)